# neural talk2 error : can not open eval.lua

Tags: neural-network

I am getting the following output on trying to run neuraltalk2

[image]

What is going wrong here?  Do I need to run this code in Torch?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The path of eval.lua cannot be found,so I add the path as follows:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlQUQ.png)